# How can I perform calculations with Camera data faster?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, callback, camera

I'm developing an Android app that takes frame-by-frame Camera data and calculates pixel color averages for each frame. The problem is that while the camera callback `onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)` is called about 24 times every second, if I put calculations in the Camera callback, the callback frequency gets significantly slowed to around 8-10 callbacks per second, which is too low.

For example:

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.e(tag, "Frame");
            }
}
```

prints "Frame" about 24 times per second, which is good. However

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                //do heavy calculations with data array
                Log.e(tag, "Frame");
            }
}
```

prints "Frame" about 8 times per second.

Is there any way to speed up the callback frequency of the Camera while still performing operations on frame data?

Answer (score 0):

Without rewriting your code, you can utilize the multicore architecture of modern devices: offload processing to a thread pool,

But quite possibly you can significantly improve performance of your algorithms by optimization. Converting to native can help, especially if you fully involve NEON vector instructions.

Major speed-up can be achieved if you rewrite your processing in RenderScript or otherwise use the power of your graphics accelerator.